# How to get responseBody from Java Exception

Tags: java, exception, httpresponse

While calling the REST service, Its giving `HttpClientErrorException`, I'm able to retrieve status code and error message, but how can I get `responseBody` ?

I'm trying the bellow code, but unable to typecast to `HttpResponse`.

```
catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {  
   // I am trying to typecast to HttpResponse, but its throwing error
     HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) e;
     String msg = response.getEntity().getContent().toString(); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: did you look up the javadocs for HttpClientErrorException?  You will see that it inherits these methods `getResponseBodyAsByteArray, getResponseBodyAsString, getResponseHeaders` - are they not suitable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpClientErrorException` extends `RestClientResponseException` which contains the method `getResponseBodyAsString()`.

So it's a mistake to cast it to `HttpResponse`, in fact `HttpClientErrorException` doesn't extend `HttpResponse`

Simply do this

```
catch(HttpClientErrorException e){  
     String body = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

For more info http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html

Comment: Thank you Flood2d.

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept the answer, if useful, thanks!